# Problema al obtener resultado de un StoredProcedure Java JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Cuando ejecuto el método me sale el error

> java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data

...cuando imprimo `rs.getRow()` imprime `0` en consola.
Si ejecuto el *stored procedure* desde MySQL todo funciona bien.

```
openConnection();
consultaSQL = "call autorizarpago(" + pagoID + ")";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(consultaSQL);
rs = ps.executeQuery(); 

consultaSQL = "call getPagoAutorizado(" + pagoID + ")";
ps = conn.prepareCall(consultaSQL);
rs = ps.executeQuery(); 

System.out.println(rs.getRow());

while(rs.next()) {
    objPago.setFechaHora(Long.parseLong(rs.getString("fechaHora")));
    String idCuenta = rs.getString("idCuenta");
    int tipoMovimiento = 1;
    objPago.setMonto(Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("monto")));
    String pFechaId =  System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
    int pFuente = 1;
    // ...
}
```

Código *stored procedure*

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getPagoAutorizado`(idPago INT)
BEGIN
SELECT pagos.fechaHora, pagos.monto, cuentas.idCuenta  
FROM pagos
INNER JOIN cuentas
ON pagos.idAlumno = cuentas.idAlumno AND pagos.idPago = idPago;
END
```

Comment: ¿En `autorizarpago` ejecutas un `UPDATE`? El mensaje de error hace pensar eso. ¿Por qué  no devuelves desde ahí los datos del pago autorizado sin tener que llamar a una segunda SP? Si tienes que conservar las dos SP, al menos **usa un objeto distinto para guardar el resultado de la llamada a `getPagoAutorizado`**

Comment: el problema esta en la linea que esta arriba del System.out.print, ósea en la ejecución de call getPagoAutorizado()

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el ResultSet  se obtiene usando `execute()` , en tu caso estas usando `executeQuery()`, **usa `execute()` en el query que realiza una actualización**:

```
consultaSQL = "call getPagoAutorizado(" + pagoID + ")";
ps = conn.prepareCall(consultaSQL);
rs = ps.execute();
```

---

- El método **`executeQuery()`** retorna un ResultSet pero este método es usado para realizar una consulta a base de datos.
- Si deseas realizar una actualización puedes usar **`execute()`** , este método va a retornar un valor `true` si la operación fue un `SELECT`, pero si la operación implica un a modificación en la base de datos como un `UPDATE`, `INSERT` o `DELETE` retornará `false`.
- Si usas **`executeUpdate()`**, el método devuelve el número de filas que coincide con la instrucción de actualización.

Comment: el método execute() devuelve un boolean, pero ya se a lo que te refieres, ya tambien lo intente con el método execute() y obtengo el objeto ResultSet con el método getResultSet y me da  el mismo error.

Comment: @Tornes los query realizan una actualización?

Comment: el primer el primer query es un SELECT y el segundo es un UPDATE, el segundo es el que publique abajo del código JAVA

Comment: @Tornes , entonces en el segundo usa execute(), pero recuerda que el ResultSet solo obtendría un false, revisa la información que agrego en mi respuesta.

Comment: Sigue con el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba relacionado con el ambito de resultSet, pues en donde lo ocupaba no tenia asignacion de valores